# How To Best Use SQL Aliases With Bookshelf.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, bookshelf.js

Project Stack: Express.js, MySQL, Bookshelf.js

I have a model called Request in Bookshelf.js. These requests have a longitude and latitude. The method that uses this model is given a longitude and latitude. I want to make a query for 50 requests that are nearest to the given set of coordinates. So if I was doing this in MySQL statements I would use a query that would look something like this.

```
var longitude = ... 
var latitude = ...

"SELECT * FROM REQUESTS" +     
"WHERE STATE_OF_REQUEST = 'unfulfilled'" +
"ORDER BY SQRT(POW(" + longitude + " - LONGITUDE, 2) + POW(" + latitude + " - LATITUDE, 2))"
```

However I dont want to use SQL statements to do this. I would rather do with the the ORM bookshelf.js.

http://bookshelfjs.org

So I was wondering if anybody help me come up with some clean code to do this.

```
Request.query(( queryItem) => {
                queryItem.limit(max);
                queryItem.where('STATE_OF_REQUEST', 'unfulfilled');
                queryItem.orderBy("SQRT(POW(" + response[0].location.lng + " - LONGITUDE, 2) + POW(" + response[0].location.lat + "- LATITUDE , 2))");
            }).fetchAll().then((models) => {
                return callBack ({
                    success: true,
                    data: models,
                });
            });
```

This code return with this error?

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'SQRT(POW(-93.0331135 - LONGITUDE, 2) + POW(41.70712109999999- LATITUDE , 2))' in 'order clause'
```

Comment: That is not a valid SQL statement though.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I changed the SQL to closer to what I wanted. I ran this script and it seemed valid.

SELECT * FROM REQUESTS  WHERE STATE_OF_REQUEST = 'unfulfilled'  ORDER BY SQRT(POW(10 - LONGITUDE, 2) + POW(15 - LATITUDE , 2));

Comment: Now it is a valid SQL statement.

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: @devius It works but I am trying to do it with Bookshelf.js.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.orderByRaw()](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-orderByRaw) from Knex:

```
queryItem.orderByRaw("SQRT(POW(" + response[0].location.lng +
  " - LONGITUDE, 2) + POW(" + response[0].location.lat +
  "- LATITUDE , 2))");
```

You're not exactly using Bookshelf in this case, but accessing the query engine that it uses directly. This way you get access to all the methods that Knex exposes, so you should refer to Knex's documentation whenever you use `.query` or `.where` in Bookshelf.